# Flutter SmartLook SDK works only on the first page

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I'm trying to use [SmartLook](https://smartlook.com) in my Flutter project. I use the latest `flutter_smartlook` package. Here is my code according to [their documentation](https://docs.smartlook.com/docs/sdk/flutter?platform=flutter):

```dart
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final SetupOptions options = (SetupOptionsBuilder('*******')
          ..Fps = 10
          ..StartNewSession = true)
        .build();

    Smartlook.setupAndStartRecording(options);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SmartlookHelperWidget(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        navigatorKey: Global.navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: AppRouter.main,
        onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.onGenerateRoute,
        onGenerateInitialRoutes: AppRouter.onGenerateInitialRoutes,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that in recordings, only the first page is visible (with very poor quality / not bad fps but just poor quality). I should mention that my first page contains a `GoogleMap` widget from [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package which fill almost two third of the entire screen. In the recordings, you can see that one third of the screen which whenever user opens a new page, that part gets updates. So I think it has something with Google maps widget but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can change recording quality in project settings [image: check this image]

Use this code :

```
    static Future<void> initSmartLook() async {
    await smartlook.preferences.setProjectKey(smartLookKey);//your project key
    await smartlook.preferences.setFrameRate(2);
    smartlook.user.setIdentifier('Your Identifier');
    smartlook.user.setName('Your Name');
    smartlook.user.setEmail('Your Email');
    await smartlook.start();

    smartlook.sensitivity.changeNativeClassSensitivity([
      SensitivityTuple(
        classType: SmartlookNativeClassSensitivity.WebView,
        isSensitive: false,
      ),
      SensitivityTuple(
        classType: SmartlookNativeClassSensitivity.WKWebView,
        isSensitive: false,
      ),
      SensitivityTuple(
        classType: SmartlookNativeClassSensitivity.EditText,
        isSensitive: false,
      ),
    ]);
    Smartlook.instance.eventListeners.registerSessionChangedListener((_) {
      //TODO
    });
  }
```